# Alguém sabe a onde encontro o código fonte do protocolo http?

Tags: c

Alguém sabe a onde encontro o código fonte do protocolo http? Se caso tiver é claro, eu gostaria de saber muito.

Comment: Código fonte do protocolo? Explique-se melhor

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616; as RFCs da IETF são o local certo para se procurar documentações de coisas da internet